# Using a simple C program how to load HTTPS web page

Tags: c, http

I am using a C web page loading program.  When I ask for a page with an"http://" prefix it loads successfully.  However, when I ask for "https://" it crashes.  If I remove the "s" then I receive:

```
Host: a.b.c
nr 90 (90)
Full Buffer header HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 17 Oct 2022 10:02:05 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Mon, 17 Oct 2022 11:02:05 GMT
Location: https://a.b.c/ViewDocument.aspx?fileid=12345678
Server: cloudflare
```

This "moved" location is the original URL that I am requesting.

When this address is used in a browser it will automatically download a PDF file - which is the ultimate aim of this code.

Some relevant coding:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stdint.h"
#ifdef __linux
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#endif
...
void receive(char *ip, char *domain, char *page){

    int sockfd, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    char header[512];
    portno = 80;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1){
        printf("error opening socket\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("socket opened\n");
    }

    memset((char *) &server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
#ifdef __WIN32
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
#else
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &(server_addr.sin_addr) );
#endif

    int err = 0;
    if( (err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) ) < 0){
        printf("failed to connect %d\n", err);
        return;
    }else{
        printf("connection successful\n");
    }

    snprintf(header, 512, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", page, domain);
    printf("Header %s\n", header);

    int nr = send(sockfd, header, tec_string_length(header), 0);
    if(nr){
        printf("nr %d (%u)\n", nr, tec_string_length(header));
    }

    char *buf;
    buf = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE_INC * sizeof(char));
    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE_INC);
    ssize_t bytes_received = recv(sockfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);

    int size = 0;
    char *new_buffer = process_header(buf, &size);
    memmove(buf, new_buffer, BUF_SIZE_INC - (new_buffer - buf) );
    load_body(sockfd, buf, size);
    puts("*****");

#ifdef __WIN32
    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
#else
    close(sockfd);
#endif

}//receive*/
```

The code is from https://gitlab.com/greggink/youtube_episode_loading_webpage (using the main_final.c file).

Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port number `portno` to `443` ? That's the default HTTPS port.

Comment: Do you know what `https` means?

Comment: The HTTP protocol is not simple. Use libcurl or another feature right library.

Comment: @Cheatah not only is the `https` "not simple", it's downright very complicated.

Comment: Thanks $curl --output ax.pdf https://a.b.c/ViewDocument.aspx?fileid=12345678 gave me the correct PDF.   I can't find curl.h even though libcurl is installed. $ curl --version
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3 Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos ...

Comment: IIRC, Ubuntu has packages "libcurl*-dev", of which you need to install one.